# How to sync my custom audio file with its transcript

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I have made a podcast application where I am able to display the generated transcript for an audio file.
So far what I have achieved looks like below, it just displays the transcript (not synced with audio):
[image]

Now I want the transcript to sync in real time with the audio being played in background and the speakers words at a particular instant must get highlighted. Also the transcript should scroll automatically based on the audio progress. Something like this :
[image]

I am using just_audio dependency. Any insights or implementation would be of great help.

I have created a custom widget to track the progress of the audio being played.
Below is its code:

```
class AudioProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const AudioProgressBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ProgressBarState>(
      valueListenable: pageManager.progressNotifier,
      builder: (_, value, __) {
        return ProgressBar(
          progress: value.current,
          buffered: value.buffered,
          total: value.total,
          onSeek: pageManager.seek,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the code of my pageManager:

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:get/instance_manager.dart';
import 'package:miniplayer/miniplayer.dart';

import 'notifiers/play_button_notifier.dart';
import 'notifiers/progress_notifier.dart';
import 'notifiers/repeat_button_notifier.dart';
import 'services/playlist_repository.dart';

class PageManager {
  // Listeners: Updates going to the UI
  final currentTranscriptionNotifier = ValueNotifier<String>('');

  // Events: Calls coming from the UI
  void init() async {
    _listenToPlaybackState();
    _listenToCurrentPosition();
    _listenToBufferedPosition();
    _listenToTotalDuration();
  }

  void play() => _audioHandler.play();

  void pause() => _audioHandler.pause();

  void seek(Duration position) => _audioHandler.seek(position);

  void playFromPlaylist(
    int index,
    bool isRecording,
  ) async {
    <initialize my controllers>
    List recording;
    late List<MediaItem> mediaItems;
    if (isRecording == true) {
      recording = <fetch data from my controller object>
          .sublist(index);
      mediaItems = recording
          .map((audio) => MediaItem(
              id: audio.Id ?? '',
              title: audio.Name ?? '',
              artist: audio.UserId ?? '',
              album: audio.albumId ?? '',
              displayDescription: audio.Transcription ?? '',
              extras: {'url': audio.Link}))
          .toList();
    } 

   void _listenToChangesInSong() {
    _audioHandler.mediaItem.listen((mediaItem) {     
      currentTranscriptionNotifier.value = mediaItem?.displayDescription ?? '';
    });
  }
  void add() {}

  void stop() => _audioHandler.stop();

  void dispose() => _audioHandler.customAction('dispose');


}
```

So basically I fetch my transcription from pagemanager and display it in my ui as follows:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                               crossAxisAlignment:
                               CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                               children: [
                                         Padding(
                                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                         top:18.0,
                                         left:16),
                                         child: Row(
                                         mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                         children: [
                                                    Text('Transcript',
                                                    style: sfSemiBold.copyWith(
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    letterSpacing: 0.2,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                    color: const Color(0xCC181D1A)),
                                        ), ],),),
                                         Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:18.0,
                                                          horizontal:16),
                                                          child: Text(
                                                          pageManager.currentTranscriptionNotifier.value,
                                                          style: sfRegular.copyWith(
                                                          fontSize:18,
                                                          height:2.0),),),],),),
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it getting the timings for words to sync? Or do you have the timings and don't know how to highlight the words? ... Please clarify :)

Comment: @dwb I want to sync the words with the audio and also highlight those which are being played in the audio at that very instant. Similar to the lyrics feature in spotify, where the currently said words from the lyrics are highlighted. I hope this clarifies my question

Comment: I understand your goal at a high level (sync the text to audio), but I'm wondering what your problem is at a lower, more concrete level. Syncing an existing transcription to audio would require the transcription is timestamped - a bit like captions on YouTube for example. If you don't have these timestamps, then you'll need to generate them somehow. Perhaps with a speech to text service, for example Deepgram. Then using the timestamps and the current audio progress, you know where in your transcript to highlight up to.

Comment: I guess more generally, your question here is not specific enough. It's a bit like asking "how do I build a rocket". An answer to that would require more space than the StackOverflow box can fit, and in reality there is a more immediate question you have, but haven't asked.

Comment: Actually I have somehow managed to generate subtitles (timestamped transcript) for the audio using python. So now I have a .srt file of the transcript, but idk how to integrate it with my ui and sync it with my audio.

Comment: In the example above I am using a normal string from my DB to display the transcript. So to break my question down, Id say, now I am able to generate a timestamped .srt file but i need insights on how to integrate it and sync with my audio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256339/discussion-between-rohit-and-dwb).